# Unable to send JSON data to webserver using curl

Tags: arrays, json, curl

I am trying to sent a curl command to a webserver to control a device in my home.  The webserver contains the following JSON data:

```
{"result":1, "error":null, "id":0, "data":{"vid":2, "did":4, "device_type":"airconditioner", "default_name":"Air Conditioner Settings", "tags":"aircon", "is_sensor":1, "is_actuator":1, "is_silent":0, "has_time_series":0, "has_subdevice_count":0, "has_state":0, "gid":"0", "guid":"xxxx", "node":"yyy", "meta":{}, "shortName":"", "subDevices":{}, "last_data":{"DA":{"amOn":false, "tempTarget":22, "mode":1, "fanSpeed":0, "enabledZones":[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]}, "timestamp":1500523622862}}
```

Using curl I can send the following PUT command to turn the device on:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"DA":{"amOn":"true"}}' https://actron.ninja.is/rest/v0/device/xxxx?user_access_token=zzzz
```

However I am stuck in sending a PUT command to change the numbers in the enabledZones array.

I have tried many variations of the command below with no success:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"DA":{"enabledZones[1]":"0"}}' https://actron.ninja.is/rest/v0/device/xxxx?user_access_token=zzzz
```

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are sending incorrect array request in json. To update array element 1 with 0, you need to use `"enabledZones":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`.

Please see if below CURL command works

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"DA":{"enabledZones":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}}' https://actron.ninja.is/rest/v0/device/xxxx?user_access_token=zzzz
```